# Регулярное выражение исключающее имеющиеся регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, node.js

Всем доброго времени суток.
Есть 3 регулярных выражения:

```
re=/^RUB$|^EUR$|^USD$/
re2=/^\/delete(RUB$|EUR$|USD$)/
re3=/^File (RUB$|EUR$|USD$)/
```

нужно создать такое выражение которое содержит в себе все остальные символы и комбинации символов кроме этих.Нужно для бота в телеграмм чтобы он реагировал на неизвестные команды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в коде наверняка есть проверка на каждое из этих регулярных выражений.

```
if(str.match(re)) {

} else if(str.match(re2)) {

} else if(str.match(re3)) {

} else {
  // вот тут делаем то что надо безо всяких дополнительных проверок и регулярок
}
```

Можно и `switch` с `default` использовать на усмотрение автора.

Comment: код выглядит примерно следующим образом:
`bot.onText(re, (msg) => {}) 
bot.onText(re2, (msg) => {})
bot.onText(re3, (msg) => {})`

Comment: @DaniilDogoff ясно, но ведь его можно переделать под вид который я написал, в любом случае это красивее чем делать исключающую регулярку

Comment: @DaniilDogoff но даже если делать исключающую регулярку её надо не строкой задавать а собирать на основе тех регулярок, так как если изменить или добавить в те регулярки, то и исключающую придётся минять, а это потенциальное место для ошибок

Answer (score 0):

Что-то ты странное делаешь. Наверняка есть нормальный способ сделать то же самое.

Но если очень хочется, то можно так:

```
/^(?!^RUB$|^EUR$|^USD$|^\/delete(RUB$|EUR$|USD$)|^File (RUB$|EUR$|USD$)/
```

упрощается до

```
/^(?!(RUB|EUR|USD|\/delete(RUB|EUR|USD)|File (RUB|EUR|USD))$/
```

Вот работающий пример (немного изменён из-за специфики html):

```css
input { box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
:valid { border-color: red; }
:invalid { border-color: green; }
```

```html
<input pattern="(?!(RUB|EUR|USD|/delete(RUB|EUR|USD)|File (RUB|EUR|USD))$).*" autofocus>
```